# intellij idea выдает Abnormal Build process Determination

Tags: java, intellij-idea

При создании простого Hello Word проекта выдает следующую ошибку.

```
Error:Abnormal build process termination: 
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.2\bin\java.exe" -Xmx700m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djdt.compiler.useSingleThread=true -Dcompile.parallel=false -Drebuild.on.dependency.change=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dio.netty.initialSeedUniquifier=-4797295383048018691 -Dfile.encoding=windows-1251 -Duser.language=ru -Duser.country=RU -Didea.paths.selector=IdeaIC2019.1 "-Didea.home.path=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3" -Didea.config.path=C:\Users\Liam\.IdeaIC2019.1\config -Didea.plugins.path=C:\Users\Liam\.IdeaIC2019.1\config\plugins -Djps.log.dir=C:/Users/Liam/.IdeaIC2019.1/system/log/build-log "-Djps.fallback.jdk.home=C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/jre64" -Djps.fallback.jdk.version=1.8.0_202-release -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:/Users/Liam/.IdeaIC2019.1/system/compile-server/projects_63a238dd/_temp_ -Djps.backward.ref.index.builder=true -Dkotlin.incremental.compilation=true -Dkotlin.incremental.compilation.js=true -Dkotlin.daemon.enabled -Dkotlin.daemon.client.alive.path=\"C:\Users\Liam\AppData\Local\Temp\kotlin-idea-8770710522028230119-is-running\" -classpath "C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/lib/jps-launcher.jar;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-10.0.2/lib/tools.jar" org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.Launcher "C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/lib/aether-dependency-resolver.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/lib/jna-platform.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/lib/maven-builder-support-3.3.9.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/lib/maven-aether-provider-3.3.9.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/lib/lz4-1.3.0.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/lib/maven-model-3.3.9.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/lib/aether-spi-1.1.0.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/lib/netty-resolver-4.1.32.Final.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/lib/httpcore-4.4.10.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/lib/commons-codec-1.10.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/lib/aether-transport-file-1.1.0.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/lib/idea_rt.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/lib/netty-buffer-4.1.32.Final.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/lib/util.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/lib/plexus-utils-3.0.22.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/lib/oro-2.0.8.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/lib/jps-builders.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/lib/commons-lang3-3.4.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/lib/plexus-component-annotations-1.6.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/lib/aether-impl-1.1.0.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/lib/jps-builders-6.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/lib/maven-repository-metadata-3.3.9.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/lib/jna.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/lib/forms_rt.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/lib/javac2.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/lib/plexus-interpolation-1.21.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/lib/netty-transport-4.1.32.Final.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/lib/jps-model.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/lib/jdom.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/lib/aether-util-1.1.0.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/lib/nanoxml-2.2.3.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/lib/maven-artifact-3.3.9.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/lib/resources_en.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/lib/netty-codec-4.1.32.Final.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/lib/forms-1.1-preview.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/lib/aether-transport-http-1.1.0.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/lib/log4j.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/lib/asm-all-7.0.1.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/lib/trove4j.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/lib/protobuf-java-3.5.1.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/lib/aether-api-1.1.0.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/lib/annotations.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/lib/platform-api.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/lib/httpclient-4.5.6.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/lib/guava-25.1-jre.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/lib/maven-model-builder-3.3.9.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/lib/netty-common-4.1.32.Final.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/lib/aether-connector-basic-1.1.0.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/lib/commons-logging-1.2.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/lib/gson-2.8.5.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/plugins/android/lib/jarutils.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/lib/guava-25.1-jre.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/plugins/android/lib/common-26.3.0.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-api-4.10.3.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/lib/gson-2.8.5.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/plugins/android/lib/jarutils.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/lib/guava-25.1-jre.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/plugins/android/lib/common-26.3.0.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-api-4.10.3.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/plugins/ant/lib/ant-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/plugins/uiDesigner/lib/jps/ui-designer-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/plugins/IntelliLang/lib/intellilang-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/plugins/Groovy/lib/groovy-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/plugins/Groovy/lib/groovy-rt-constants.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/plugins/eclipse/lib/eclipse-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/plugins/eclipse/lib/common-eclipse-util.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/plugins/maven/lib/maven-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/plugins/devkit/lib/devkit-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/plugins/Kotlin/lib/jps/kotlin-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-stdlib.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-reflect.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/plugins/android/lib/jps/android-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/plugins/android/lib/android-common.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/plugins/android/lib/build-common.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/plugins/android/lib/android-rt.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/plugins/android/lib/android-extensions-ide.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/plugins/android/lib/sdk-common-26.3.0.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/plugins/android/lib/common-26.3.0.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/plugins/android/lib/repository-26.3.0.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/plugins/android/lib/sdklib-26.3.0.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/plugins/android/lib/jarutils.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/plugins/android/lib/layoutlib-api-26.3.0.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/plugins/android/lib/manifest-merger-26.3.0.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/plugins/javaFX/lib/javaFX-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/plugins/javaFX/lib/common-javaFX-plugin.jar" org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain 127.0.0.1 49722 df3bdf50-61b1-4580-9bec-4890a91abfe8 C:/Users/Liam/.IdeaIC2019.1/system/compile-server
Build process started. Classpath: C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3/lib/jps-launcher.jar;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-10.0.2/lib/tools.jar
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:49722; reason: failed to create a child event loop
java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create a child event loop
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:88)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:58)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:47)
    at io.netty.channel.MultithreadEventLoopGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventLoopGroup.java:59)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:77)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:72)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:59)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain.main(BuildMain.java:90)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:58)
Caused by: io.netty.channel.ChannelException: failed to open a new selector
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.openSelector(NioEventLoop.java:168)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.<init>(NioEventLoop.java:142)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.newChild(NioEventLoopGroup.java:127)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.newChild(NioEventLoopGroup.java:36)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:84)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to establish loopback connection
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:94)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:61)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl.<init>(PipeImpl.java:171)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SelectorProviderImpl.openPipe(SelectorProviderImpl.java:50)
    at java.base/java.nio.channels.Pipe.open(Pipe.java:155)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.<init>(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:127)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorProvider.openSelector(WindowsSelectorProvider.java:44)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.openSelector(NioEventLoop.java:166)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:454)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:446)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:648)
    at java.base/java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.open(SocketChannel.java:194)   at java.base/sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer$LoopbackConnector.run(PipeImpl.java:127)   at java.base/sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:76)  ... 24 moreExiting.
```

---

Помогла переустановка программы, а также полное отключение брандмауэра.